Software login behavior beyond acceptable? (480+ records in 9 seconds)
So, I'm receiving complaints from some user about this accounting software crashing on them too frequently. One user in particular says it is becoming unbearable working like this.
It happens on more than one PC, but as said, one seems to suffer from it the most; but it might be just because how much the users actually uses the application due to her job.
I have not found any traces of what is happening, there are no error messages, no records in the event viewers at the PC or Server. I' ve tested network connectivity and it is solid, and there are no anomalies there when the crashes occur.
No usage patterns to trigger the crash either.
If there is any internal logging system on the application I have no access to it.
The odd thing I've found are these large numbers of login records in the Security Audit. As a reference, between 8:35:01 and 8:35:09 there are 487 records with sequences of events 4776,4648,4624,4672,4634,4634.
These seem to be complete cycles of logging in and out, and given these are Type 4 (Batch?) I guess it is possible that the software has some scripted process at the server doing this.
It makes me wonder if this could be hammering something and end up kicking the users out (overall server resources do not seem to be an issue though).
But before I go to the devs and start an argument about whether or not this is a real issue I'd like to know if this is a behavior to be concerned about or it is normal and I shouldn't care about it as a possible cause for the problems.
FWIW: Win server 2016 Std and W 10 clients.
Thanks in advance.
